# Need to Get the current DateTime in the Talend Studio?

Tags: java, string, date, datetime, talend

I am working the Talend studio tool for data migration. Now I want to set the Current DateTime in the Date field.
I get the DateTime from this code `TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` but it returns String type data. But I need `Date` type to insert.Is there any String to date (Sample insert is like this:`1999-12-13 16:14:48`) conversion is in the Talend Studio.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use routine function `TalendDate.parseDate` to convert a `String` to a `Date`.

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", yourStringData);
```

If you want the current datetime:

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

### **But this makes no sense.**

Parsedate function is prepared to receive a string and convert it to a `Date` object. `Date` objects have it's own format, so you don't have to care how is stored, **you need to change the `Date` format in the moment you show it, but not when you store it**:

```
// this will produce a correct Date Object to store in your Date field
Date currentDate = TalendDate.getCurrentDate();
```

When you need to show/print it use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for example if you want to show 2015-07-05 16:00:00 you must do like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss);
System.out.println("My date formatted is: " + sdf.format(currentDate ));
```

Comment: TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))Shall I use Like this code. Mr.Jordi

Comment: I want to insert the current date and time like this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".So shall I use this  
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")). @Jordi Castilla

Comment: read my updated answer, you are missing important things, hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

its very simple with the use of DateFormat in java

```
public static void convert(String inputDate) throws ParseException {

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d = format.parse(inputDate); // example 1999-12-13 16:14:48
                System.out.println(d);
    }
```